# VB.NET Compare 2 String Lists of different lengths for identical matches, lists will have duplicate values and List1 needs everything in List2

Tags: vb.net, linq

Vb.Net check 2 scrambled string lists of different lengths for
identical value matches, both lists may have duplicate repeating
values and those need to be accounted for. List1 needs to have the
same count of values that's inside List2. Both lists will always
have values and List1 will always be larger than or equal size to
List2, never smaller than than List2.

**Example = True - because List2 called for F100 & F200 and those are
in List1.**
List1 = (F100, F200, F300, F400)
List2 = (F100, F200)

**Example = False - because List1 did not have quantity 2 of F200, it
only had F200 appear once.**
List1 = (F100, F200, F300, F100)
List2 = (F100, F200, F200)

**Example = True - because List1 has quantity 2 of F100, F200, & F300.
List1 had extra items, which is fine.**
List1 = (F300, F200, F100,F300, F200,F100, F400, F500, F600)
List2 = (F100, F200, F300, F100, F200, F300)

I would like to have a boolean value set to false if List1 does not
have matches of everything Inside List2. My example code is below but
it does not work for duplicate values.

```
Dim lot_equal As Boolean = True
For Each difference In List2.Except(List1)
lot_equal = False
Next
```

Comment: I wouldn't guess there is a way to do this using only Linq functions, I'd guess you'll need to hand-code it.  You may want to use the implementation of various Linq functions for reference on potential techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [Remove(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove) method which removes the *first* occurrence of an object from a list.

If you don't want the list changed, create a suitable clone of it in the function. The function name and parameter names could do with some improvement:

```
Module Module1

    Function X(Of T)(a As List(Of T), b As List(Of T)) As Boolean

        If b.Count > a.Count Then
            Return False
        End If

        ' N.B. Use a clone of a if you do not want it altered.

        For Each q In b
            If Not a.Contains(q) Then
                Return False
            Else
                a.Remove(q)
            End If
        Next

        Return True

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim list1 = New List(Of Integer) From {100, 200, 300, 400}
        Dim list2 = New List(Of Integer) From {100, 200}
        Console.WriteLine(X(list1, list2))

        list1 = New List(Of Integer) From {100, 200, 300, 100}
        list2 = New List(Of Integer) From {100, 200, 200}
        Console.WriteLine(X(list1, list2))

        list1 = New List(Of Integer) From {300, 200, 100, 300, 200, 100, 400, 500, 600}
        list2 = New List(Of Integer) From {100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300}
        Console.WriteLine(X(list1, list2))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
True
False
True
```

Comment: Brilliant! This works like a charm! Thanks so much i spent days working on this.

Answer (score 2):

Can do this with LINQ

```
<Extension()>
Function IsIn(Of T)(list2 As List(Of T), list1 As List(Of T)) As Boolean

    Dim d1 = list1.GroupBy(Function(x) x).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) g.Count())
    Return list2.GroupBy(Function(x) x).All(Function(g) d1.ContainsKey(g.Key) AndAlso d1(g.Key) >= g.Count())

End Function
```

How does it work?

Turns the first list into a dictionary, mapping a number to the count of times it appears (so `List1 = (F100, F200, F300, F400)` becomes a dictionary of 4 entries, count 1 each)

Then it groups the second list up by entry, and asks a) if all the keys are in the first list and b) does the count from the first list equal or greater than the count of the second list.

It can also be done with a Lookup:

```
<Extension()>
Function IsIn(Of T)(list2 As List(Of T), list1 As List(Of T)) As Boolean

    Dim lu = list1.ToLookup(Function(x) x)
    Return list2.GroupBy(Function(x) x).All(Function(g) lu(g.Key).Count >= g.Count())

End Function
```

..and it has the nice facility that you don't need to query the presence of the key first - calling for lookup on an non existent key produces an empty sequence..

..but they're less commonly encountered than Dictionary so it's a bit more "huh? what does this do?"

By making it an extension, you can call it in a very natural way:

```
Dim result = list2.IsIn(list1)
```

Comment: Yes, this does work too, would you happen to know which would work faster computationally with large lists, the custom function or linq extension method?

Comment: I'd expect these approaches to be faster on large datasets than Andrew's suggestion, because that uses nested loops (and list modification), and this uses a hashed lookup.. For smaller sets, the process of creating a Dictionary may be more expensive than nested loops. If absolute performance is the goal I'd skip LINQ too and write a dictionary direct approach, especially if there are multiple List2 to be tested against a static List1. As to indicative timings, I genuinely suggest you bench test them all; noone can say with any certainty what a perf test will come out as for your exact data